# How is the destination that an uninitialized pointer in c points to determined?

Tags: c, pointers

I know that if a pointer is declared in C (and not initialized), it will be pointing to a "random" memory address which could contain anything.

How is where it actually points to determined though? Presumably it's not truly random, since this would be inefficient and illogical.

Comment: I would imagine that this is implementation specific, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable for an explanation of how it could be done

Comment: A compiler is at liberty to choose any convenient implementation for undefined behaviour.  Reading whatever value happens to be at a given stack or heap address is common for uninitialised pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this pointer is defined outside of all functions (or is `static`), it will be initialized to `NULL` before `main()` gets control.

If this pointer is created in the heap via `malloc(sizeof(sometype*))`, it will contain whatever happens to be at its location. It can be the data from the previously allocated and freed buffer of memory. Or it can be some old control information that `malloc()` and `free()` use to manage the lists of the free and allocated blocks. Or it can be garbage if the OS (if any) does not clear program's memory or if its system calls for memory allocation return uninitialized memory and so those can contain code/data from previously run programs or just some garbage that your RAM chips had when the system was powered on.

If this pointer is local to a function (and is not `static`), it will contain whatever has been at its place on the stack. Or if a CPU register is allocated to this pointer instead of a memory cell, it will contain whatever value the preceding instructions have left in this register.

So, it won't be totally random, but you rarely have full control here.

Comment: May it not also be a trap representation?

Comment: @Anonymous It can be a trap representation for the pointer type. It doesn't change much if anything, though.

Answer (score 3):

Uninitialized is undefined.  Generally speaking, when the pointer is allocated the memory space is not cleared, so whatever the memory contained is now a pointer.  It is random, but it is also efficient in the sense that the memory location is not being changed in the operation.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable

> Languages such as C use stack space for variables, and the collection
>   of variables allocated for a subroutine is known as a stack frame.
>   While the computer will set aside the appropriate amount of space for
>   the stack frame, it usually does so simply by adjusting the value of
>   the stack pointer, and does not set the memory itself to any new state
>   (typically out of efficiency concerns). Therefore, whatever contents
>   of that memory at the time will appear as initial values of the
>   variables which occupy those addresses.

Although I would imagine this is implementation specific.

Furthermore you should probably always initialize your pointers, see the answer provided at [How do you check for an invalid pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482315/how-do-you-check-for-an-invalid-pointer) and the link given on the first answer: -

http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-1.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as the C standard is concerned, an uninitialized pointer doesn't point *anywhere*. It is illegal to dereference it. Thus it is impossible in principle to observe its target, and thus the target simply *doesn't exist* for all intents and purposes.

If you want a trite analogy, asking for the value of an uninitialized pointer is like asking for the value of the smallest positive real number, or the value of the last digit of π.

(The corolloary is that only Chuck Norris can dereference an uninitialized pointer.)

Comment: I think you can look at the value of an uninitialized pointer without causing undefined behavior (for example by `memcpy`ing the bytes into a `char[sizeof(void*)]`). That way, you may learn that it's a valid pointer and so dereference it. Asking for the value of an uninitialised pointer is more like asking for the last digit of an indeterminate real number. It may have one, or it may not.

Answer (score 0):

It is implementation specific / undefined behavior. It's possible the pointer was automatically initialized to NULL... or it is just whatever value is in memory at the time.

A pointer is an address in memory that points to another address in memory. The fact that it's not initialized does not mean that the pointer itself doesn't have an address, it only means that the address of the thing it points to is not known. So, either the compiler initialized it to NULL by default, or the address is whatever was in memory in the pointer's variable space at the time.

Answer (score 0):

In large part, it is like an unerased whiteboard when you enter class. If you draw a box on part of the board but do not erase what is in the box, then what is in the box?

It is whatever was left there previously.

Similarly, if you allocate space for a pointer but do not erase the space, then what is in the space?

Data may be left over from earlier parts of your program or from special code that runs before any normal part of your program (such as the `main` function) starts running. (The special code may load and link certain libraries, set up a stack, and otherwise prepare the environment needed by a C program.) On embedded systems, rather than typical multi-user systems, data might be left over from previous processes. Quite likely, the previous use of the space was for something other than a pointer, so the value in it does not make sense when interpreted as a pointer. Its value as a pointer might point somewhere but not be meaningful in any way.

**However, you cannot rely on this.** The C standard does not define the behavior when you use an uninitialized object with automatic storage duration. In many C implementations, an uninitialized pointer will simply contain left over data. But, in some C implementations, the system may detect that you are using an uninitialized object and cause your program to crash. (Other behaviors are possible too.)