# Check if i can write to memory

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, memory, access-violation

I have a code that is accessing specific memory and writing to it
:

```
*addr = _data;
```

but there are cases, in which `addr` variable can point to *inaccessible memory*, that cannot be read or written to (for instance, `nullptr`). In such case the code above should not be executed. The question is, how do i check if a memory address in `addr` is valid? I have learned that i cannot catch *Access violation exceptions*, neither i can use `IsBadReadPtr` WinAPI function, because it is basically useless. How should i check for such cases?

Comment: ***how do i check if a memory address in "addr" is valid?*** You can check against nullptr however you can't really check if it is valid. The best advice I will give is to avoid code like this. Modern `c++` is about using the standard library containers and smartpointers. I have not written code like your example in over a decade.

Comment: Perhaps `if (addr == nullptr)` or `if (!ptr)`? What do you mean by _is valid_?

Comment: All you can do is see if it is null.  You can't tell if a non null address is valid.

Comment: I am absolutely aware that i should never write code like this. I am writing this solely to test low level stuff, so i have to write to a random point in memory

Comment: @Ron by "valid" i mean writable and readable so my code will not throw access violation

Comment: You can't. You might be able to write to memory, but doing so corrupts your program.

Comment: ***but doing so corrupts your program*** Exactly! What you are doing here is Undefined Behavior even if the memory is writable in your program's address space. One could use VirtualQuery to check every address before hand but its still UB.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that is what i need. I need to corrupt my program without system exceptions

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to write defensive library functions which take an address to write into from the caller, and you have no control over the caller?

Comment: ***without system exceptions*** I don't think you can totally avoid that even if you are careful to check every address first.

Comment: **i have to write to a random point in memory** No; it's not random.  Computers famously have needed a lot of effort to do random at all.  Programs that do `int tmp = *(int*)rand())` or visa versa get every segfault they deserve

Comment: Walk through the address space, and when you find a writeable page, write to it. Seems rather pointless to me.

Comment: Just because you can read/write the memory address in question does not mean that you __should__ read/write at the memory address.  It might not be owned by your program but by the runtime-support, bits of the OS etc

Comment: @David Heffernan, to understand your comment, I am focusing on `stack` .. how could memory be invalid in `stack` though! provided that a pointer check comes before reading -> `if (addr) { *addr = _data;}`

Comment: @RichardCritten or it could be owned by the program ... like the middle of the stack ... good luck debugging that problem

Comment: [This sounds quite a bit XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (Maybe even XYZ), With a bit more information about the goal someone may be able to guide you out of this mess.

Comment: @UKMonkey yup it's the programmers version of Russian Roulette.

Comment: Without a valid use case, the question seems broad ..

Comment: @Mohammad I've no idea what you mean

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I am considering the normal case of declaring a pointer and consuming its address ... this is because OP is derefrencing a pointer

Comment: @Mohammad Pointers are not restricted to point to the stack. Otherwise how would dynamic memory ever be useful?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I know that, thats why I said, I am considering stack (vs. are not putting it in heap with `new`)

Comment: @Mohammad We don't really care what you are doing, these comments should relate to the question that was asked

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ - Check if pointer is pointing to valid memory (Can't use NULL checks here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787650/c-check-if-pointer-is-pointing-to-valid-memory-cant-use-null-checks-here)

Comment: @UKMonkey i can't even imaging a person stupid enough to do this. I, personally am deliberately trying to crash to program

Comment: Your question is asking how **not** to crash a program. Can't you just make up your mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know, whether an address is writable, write to it. Wrap the code in an [SEH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657.aspx) handler, and take it from there.

You cannot reliably query writeability (using [VirtualQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902.aspx), for example), since your process' address space is in constant flux. Doing so introduces a [TOCTOU race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).

Comment: And if the write succeeds (no exception) and the C++ program did not (logically) own the memory but was part of the runtime-support etc what state is the program in?

Comment: @RichardCritten: The question was asking about writing to random memory, and I answered that question. I don't know what difference it makes, whether that memory is owned by the C++ runtime support, the Universal CRT, or the application. The OP wants UB without immediately terminating the process and I told them how to get UB without immediately terminating the process. I don't know, why this would be helpful, and cannot imagine what problem this would be the solution to. But that's not on me to judge either.

Comment: @IInspectable, But I don't get that! when your _program_ declare a pointer, its OS responsibility to track that address and make sure it does not corrupt .. I feel I am missing something!

Comment: @MohammadKanan: The OS doesn't know, what a pointer is. That's a programming language concept. The OS knows what addresses are, and it will protect against unauthorized memory access. It will not (and can not) protect against authorized (but invalid) memory access. C++ is not Java. The OS (or runtime, rather) doesn't track diddly.

Comment: @IInspectable, I know, I said _OS track that **address**_, but what I really stuck with is _invalid mem access_! .. the only case I know is when you `delete` your pointer and later accedently try to access it

Comment: @mohammad You can just stuff an arbitrary address into a pointer variable. Exactly as the asker is apparently doing in an act of self harm.

Comment: @MohammadKanan: `*(int*)0 = 42;`? `*(float*)0xBAADF00D = 7.0f;`? `*(bool*)0xBABE2BED = true;`? \*me shrugs\*.

Comment: @IInspectable i am doing this exactly to crash my application, not to make a good design. So how do i wrap in it SEH handler? As far as i am concerned, this is not possible with Windows exceptions

Comment: @Eugen1344: If you attempt to crash your application, then you do not need to do any error recovery. `*(int*)0 = 42;` is sufficient. That is not clear from your question, though.

Comment: @IInspectable no, it's not. I don't want to have access violation exception as i clearly said in my topic

Comment: @Eugen1344: So then, what is your interpretation of *"crash"*. A process being shut down due to an access violation is a common interpretation of *"crash"*.

Comment: @IInspectable, ah really clear, appreciate your patience!

Comment: @IInspectable My definition is a process, being shut down due to a random error, not because of a raised system exception

Comment: @Eugen1344: What isn't random about a system exception?

Comment: What is motivating this question?

Answer (score 1):

Use [VirtualQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902.aspx) to obtain a page's protection and see if the region the pointer points to is writeable.

But note that this should not be used to conceal bad design. Make sure all pointers and references are valid when used.

Comment: An example for this specific question might make your answer a good one ;)